# Asterisk and PHP - music on hold?

Tags: php, asterisk

I'm using PHP and Asterisk to allow clients to initiate a call to us via our website. We want an audio file to play when the first extension picks up, which is already recorded. My question: Is this something that is configurable on the PHP side of things, or should that be configured in Asterisk? If so, where? I am unable to find an action to specify a path or file name for in PHP.

Here's a chunk of my PHP script to initiate the call

```
$socket = fsockopen($host, 5038, $errnum, $errstr, $timeout) or die("Connection failed");
    fputs($socket, "Action: login\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Events: off\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Username: $username\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Secret: $password\r\n\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Action: originate\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Channel: $strChannel\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "WaitTime: $timeout\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "CallerId: $callId\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Exten: $number\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Context: $strContext\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Priority: $strPriority\r\n\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");
```

**EDIT**
I'm aware of the musiconhold.conf file - but I'm looking for a way to execute it here if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have create musiconhold class and attach class to channel.

Code you show just create call, it not show any dialplan so no way answer your question correctly.

Simplest way is supply m(musicclass) param to  dial command on second channel.

More complex ways can use more dialplan tricks or on-answer-macro( M param)

Since you not demonstrate any asterisk-related knowledge, nice idea is first read book about how asterisk work. I can recomend ORelly's "Asterisk the Future of Telephony".

Comment: Thank you. I'm a PHP developer that's been put onto this project, so it sounds like I need to read the book. Unfortunately only the owner has access to the dialplan configuration files, which is why I was hoping to accomplish it via the call creation.

Comment: You can use instead of Exten&context other form with "Application: Dial" and "Data: Local/$number\@$strContext/n,,m",but note that this way you mess CDRs. Anyway dooing dialout application without asterisk expertise result very buggy systems. For example it can hangs if you put alot of channels same time or no channel availible.